# consuming both string and object message from a queue through spring integration

Tags: jms, spring-integration

I have a queue in which there can be text message also and object message also my task is if there are pending messages on queue then to consume them and write into a file which is happening in caseof text message but it is not happening in case of object message

so please advise how i will consume and write the object message simply into the text file for example below is the is the queue which contain object message

```
ioa.exception.retry.object
```

now it contains object message and some times string message also i want to consume the message from the above queue for all messages types

so below is the my configuratipon in which sender part i have commented out and enabled only consumer part please advise how can i overcome of consuming object message problem also

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"

    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <int:poller id="poller" default="true">
        <int:interval-trigger interval="200" />
    </int:poller>



    <int:channel id="input">
        <int:queue capacity="10" />
    </int:channel>

    <bean id="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
            <props>
                <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory
                </prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">tcp://lrtys2.fm.absgrp.net:745</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">xyz</prop>
                <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">xyz</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tibcoEMSConnFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
            <ref bean="tibcoEMSJndiTemplate" />
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>GenericConnectionFactory</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tibcosendJMSTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref bean="tibcoEMSConnFactory" />
        </property>
        <property name="defaultDestinationName">
            <value>ioa.exception.retry.object</value>
        </property>
        <property name="pubSubDomain">
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
        <property name="receiveTimeout">
            <value>120000</value>
        </property>
    </bean>




    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="input" 
        destination-name="ioa.exception.retry.object" connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory" />


<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn" concurrent-consumers="10"
        destination-name="ioa.exception.retry.object"  connection-factory="tibcoEMSConnFactory"
        channel="jmsInChannel" />

    <int:channel id="jmsInChannel" />



 <file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesout"  channel="jmsInChannel" directory="C:\\asdel"
 filename-generator="generatorr" />

<bean id="generatorr" class="com.rbs.tibco.TimestampTextGenerator">
    </bean>




</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with the object; you can add a payload type router between the jms adapter and the file adapter - send Strings to the file adapter directly, send objects to a `<transformer/>` to convert to a String and then to the file adapter.

Or you can just put an `<object-to-string-transformer/>` between the jms and file adapters - it will be a no-op for the String object and will call `toString()` on the object.

If you just want to discard the objects, then send them to `nullChannel`.

Please read the [reference document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/) for information about these components.

Comment: Thanks the very first option is perfect can you please show a bit how router will verify on runtime that message is string one or object one  and also how to attach router between jms adapter and file adapter Thanks in advance

Comment: Please **read the documentation** [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-payloadtyperouter) and then come back here if there is something there that you don't understand.